# ValidationError on formset after user stopped POST request with browser goback

Tags: django

I have a django admin form containing a multiple files field and some inlines formsets after.
When user's connexion is slow, it happens they close the page or go back to the previous page (no patience or any other reason) while files are still uploading during POST form submission.
They do not see any errors, simply the form won't be saved. So I'm working on helping them to reduce request size...

But it generates ValidationError on server side, with "Missing management form", since only a part of the form data was received when user terminates the request, because the formset fields are coming after the multiple files field.
Does anyone has an idea to prevent such errors to be triggered?

Thanks.

Django 2.2.28

Comment: [Extended support for the Django 2.2 release series ended](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) on *April 11, 2022* - please upgrade to a supported release, and use that releases documentation to validate your deployment settings. You very likely do not need to process partial requests, and this issue together with a few related ones will go away after just applying current software version and configuration best practices.